# Setting TTL in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, ttl

Is it necessary to SET something while updating the TTL in Cassandra?

I have a table like this,

```
CREATE TABLE session(
  tokenId text PRIMARY KEY,
  username text);
```

I insert the data like this,

```
INSERT INTO session(tokenId, username) VALUES ('123123123123','admin') USING TTL 30;
```

I update the TTL like this,

```
UPDATE session USING TTL 30 SET username = 'admin' WHERE tokenid = '123123123123' IF EXISTS;
```

where It makes me forcefully update the '**username**', Update demands a set, Any way to just update the TTL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very tricky question. Let me try my best to explain my understanding.

Basically, cassandra doesn't allow you to update TTL for a row. TTL is maintained for **each** column as mentioned [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useExpireExample.html). Coming back to your example, the `insert` statement with `TTL` value will create the same TTL for all columns in insert statement. Meanwhile, `update` statement is only for intended columns (e.g. `username`) only. Hope it helps.

> Both the INSERT and UPDATE commands support setting a time for data in
>   a column to expire. Use CQL to set the expiration time (TTL).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Still I am not able to understand completely, my question is, Is it possible to just update the TTL alone without updating any column?

Comment: the answer is no. As TTL is maintained per column, we must mention column name for such update. As per current syntax of update statement, it must be <column name> = <column value>. Even though, we can pass the same value, but still it's need to be there. I assume you are looking for something like `update table name using TTL <ttl value> for <column name> where ...`, but it's not supported in current CQL syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: so does it mean that in case of UPDATE query (I mentioned in question) will set the expiry for only username column and not the tokenId? I am able to see that the entire row is deleted

Comment: Yes, it's for the username only. However, the TTL for tokenId might be coming from your insert statement or default TTL (in table schema). Basically, TTL in insert statement will apply for all columns.

Comment: Sorry, Please bear with me, I didn't get the point, So does this mean, Even TTL for any one of the columns got expired will delete the entire row?

Comment: No. If TTL for primary key is expired, then it will remove the row. For other column, cassandra will make it null/blank. What I said is based on your example, after insert, all columns will have TTL as 30. Then later you check the table again, the primary key might be expired as well, hence got removed. The scenario needs to be precise with timing and order.

Comment: No. This doesn't seem what's happening here, 1) Initially I set the TTL for insert as 30 seconds 2) Updated one of the column (username) with TTL 100 seconds. Expected thing is that the row needs to be deleted after 30 seconds Irrespective of update since the primary key is still having 30 seconds TTL but the row got expired only after 100.

Comment: Oh sorry, I just checked again, actually there is no TTL concept for primary key (it's my mistake, sorry about this). The row will get deleted once all non-primary key got expired. You can use ttl function to check if the column is already expired or not e.g. `select tokenid, ttl(username) from session`.

Comment: This ttl (column) helped :) Thanks Much

Comment: you are welcome, hope it clear now. Sorry for confusion